# Brother MFC-J5910DW shows 'Paper Jam' permanently

Tags: printer

I have run through the clearing process several times and cannot find even the tiniest scrap but the screen still says there is a jam and it won't change. Do I just throw it at the wall and buy another one?

Comment: You might consider contacting Brother about the problem.  They might have known work around

Answer (score 1):

My model is different, but maybe my remedy can give you and others inspiration.

I had the same kind of problem with a Brother MFC-6710DW, only three years old and not using it daily. After many hours cleaning the outside and inside of the printer, the real solution for me was: cleaning the little plastic rolls (12!) behind/under the bigger and long grey rough metallic roll behind the print head. This is where the paper passes just before it's getting printed.

It's not easy to clean them because the little rolls move backwards when you touch them. I used a rounded kind of screwdriver covered with a damp cloth, trying to avoid to scratch them. You can roll the rolls by rolling the big grey roll.

The little rolls (especially the middle ones) were partly covered with paper fibres. I cleaned them a bit (took a long time), I certainly didn't succeed to remove all the white dirt. Immediately after cleaning the error did not disappear. But after 24 hours (let's call it: dry time): tadaa, no error message!

After letting the machine clean the print head the printer worked as before.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps Brother suggests if you continue getting the error after clearing the jam. It's a good idea to follow these even if you think you got it all. There may be a small piece somewhere.

[I still receive the error message "Paper Jam" after I removed the jammed paper.](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/BSC/public/eu/eu_ot/en/faq/faq/000000/002900/000018/faq002918_000.html?reg=eu&c=eu_ot&lang=en&prod=mfcj5910dw_all&Cat=11)

If that doesn't work, the site states the following:

> If the error message continues to appear, please contact Brother
>   Customer Service from "Contact Us."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I thought my printer spoiled, after 1 month try to fixed it. But somehow my last try, manage to find one small piece of paper stuck in the roller at the side near printer head, in between gears. Now my print50 error solved. Printer is back in action.

Answer (score 0):

Mine had some ink splash on the two transparent strips that guide the printhead. I had to clean them with a mildly wet cloth.

One has some tiny black markers on it to help align the printhead and one is translucent white, also goes by the name, encoder strip. Mine had two of them.

http://www.brother-usa.com/FAQs/Solution.aspx?FAQID=200000020304&ProductID=DC&Keyword=#.Vn5L_zYvFSU

Answer (score 0):

I had a slightly different error:  "No Paper".  For my printer, a $5 part fixed it: Brother Feeder Cam Lever (part LY2579001). See [Brother MFC-7860DW No Paper](https://superuser.com/questions/1562013/brother-mfc-7860dw-no-paper/1562014#1562014) for details.